# Aggregate Javadoc for Android project with multiple library modules

Tags: android, gradle, javadoc

I've gone through almost entire Internet in search of a way how to aggregate Javadocs in the project consisting of separate library modules into single Javadoc.

There is a plugin that apparently allows to do that:
https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-aggregate-javadocs-plugin

However, if I run the command specified by the plugin Gradle finds the task and executes it but no output directory is generated.

Any help how to build single Javadoc from multiple modules much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  Same problem here :(

Answer (score 7):

I managed to get it working some time ago, apologies for a late response. The solution for aggregatable Javadoc creation is the following:

1. In each of the subprojects maintained within the project create a task generating the Javadoc:

   ```
   android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->

   task("generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Javadoc) {
       destinationDir = project.file("$project.projectDir/javadoc/$project.PROJECT_NAME") //Project name in the Project's gradle.properties
       title = "A title of my project - $project.PROJECT_VERSION_NAME" //Project version name in the Project's gradle.properties
       description "Generates Javadoc for $variant.name."
       source = variant.javaCompile.source
       ext.androidJar ="${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
       classpath = files(variant.javaCompile.classpath.files) + files(ext.androidJar) + project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
       options {
           memberLevel = org.gradle.external.javadoc.JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC //change the modifier according to your needs
           links "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/"
           linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference", "${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
       }
       exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
       exclude '**/R.java'
   }

     task("bundle${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc", type: Jar) {
       baseName = "Compass API - ($version)"
       description "Bundles Javadoc into zip for $variant.name."
       classifier = "javadoc"
       from tasks["generate${variant.name.capitalize()}Javadoc"]
     }
   }
   ```

The configuration above adds a Javadoc generation task for each buildVariant of your subproject. At this point you can you can generate Javadoc for each module separately by typing

```
gradle :myRootProject:mySubproject:generateDebugJavadoc
gradle :myRootProject:mySubproject:generateReleaseJavadoc
gradle :myRootProject:mySubproject:generateMyFancyFlavourDebugJavadoc
gradle :myRootProject:mySubproject:generateMyFancyFlavourReleaseJavadoc
```

If you use JRE 8 the following configuration disables errors raised by doclint during the Javadoc build ([explanation in greater detail here](http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html))

```
   if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
     tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
         // disable the crazy super-strict doclint tool in Java 8
         //noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
         options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
     }
    }
```

2. To aggregate Javadocs of each submodules into a single one create a Plugin in to `build.gradle` which will add a task to the submodule a partial Javadoc generation of which you are interested in:

   ```
    class JavadocAggregationPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    static final String AGGREGATE_JAVADOCS_TASK_NAME = 'aggregateJavadocs'

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        Project rootProject = project.rootProject
        rootProject.gradle.projectsEvaluated {
           Set<Project> librarySubprojects = getLibraryProjects(rootProject)
            if (!librarySubprojects.isEmpty()) {
               rootProject.task(AGGREGATE_JAVADOCS_TASK_NAME, type: Javadoc) {
                    description = 'Aggregates Javadoc API documentation of all subprojects.'
                    group = JavaBasePlugin.DOCUMENTATION_GROUP
                    dependsOn librarySubprojects.generateReleaseJavadoc //please note that generateReleaseJavadoc is the name of the separate Javadoc generation task in each library module

                    source librarySubprojects.generateReleaseJavadoc.source
                    destinationDir rootProject.file("$rootProject.buildDir/docs/javadoc") //Javadoc destination directory
                    classpath = rootProject.files(librarySubprojects.generateReleaseJavadoc.classpath)
                }
            }
        }
    }

   private Set<Project> getLibraryProjects(Project rootProject) {
       rootProject.subprojects.findAll { subproject -> subproject.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.library") } //In this case every library module is selected
   }
   }
   ```

Finally, include your plugin to the gradle configuration in the Project's `build.gradle` below your plugin definition.

```
apply plugin: JavadocAggregationPlugin
```

3. By doing this and rebuilding gradle's configuration you should be able to create aggregated Javadoc in specified directory by typing the following command via cli:

   ```
   gradle aggregateJavadocs
   ```

Hope that helps somehow.

Helpful link: [Android Gradle DSL](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html#N10009)

Comment: That plugin code is 1:1 of [Nebula Aggregate Javadocs Plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-aggregate-javadocs-plugin) source.

Comment: Yes, mostly. The only disitinction is about the directories that being found -  "com.android.library" plugin is taken into account only.

Comment: I've posted an alternative solution to producing aggregate javadoc documentation: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71906540/android-aar-depending-on-aar-fails-with-javadoc-generation/72564890#72564890 .  I've not tried dawid solution, but I've got strong reasons to believe it might not be working in later versions of android studio.